# cordova android build fails with a strange exception

Tags: android, cordova

It seems like suddenly my android build for cordova won't work. I get the following message:
.../platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
.../platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/media/AudioPlayer.java:529: error: cannot find symbol

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have issue with cordova media plugin. The plugin or the android platform seems corrupted.

Try the following:

1. Remove android platform
2. Remove cordova media plugin
3. Re-add the cordova media plugin
4. Re-add android platform
5. Rebuild android platform